Is there a FHIR API call to get all the FHIR events within a particular duration
Currently I am using Azure FHIR service to do CRUD on various resources, I want to fetch all the events happening on my fhir service since last 5 hours using FHIR API
I have tried the following process but I am getting 404 not found:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/$events?api-version=2022-12-01
Following is the error I am getting while fetching the above request:
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/$events?api-version=2022-12-01'.
please let me know how to get all the events withing particular duration using FHIR aPI

Have you had a look at the auditing capabilities in Azure FHIR? Read more here on how to enable it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/azure-api-for-fhir/enable-diagnostic-logging
or you could look at Events (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/events/events-overview)
Assuming you want to use FHIR Subscriptions, that is not something that just works out of the box, you have to actually set it up by creating a subscription to resource changes for the resource(s) you are interested in and from then on, you will get notifications when those resources change. Read more about how FHIR subscriptions work https://hl7.org/fhir/R4/subscription.html
Lastly, you could use the inbuilt FHIR _history (https://build.fhir.org/http.html#history) to view changes that have happened since a given date/time, using the _since parameter e.g.
Get all changes to Patient resources since the specified date/time
https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient/_history?_since=2024-07-25T07:00:00Z

or all changes to all resources since the specified date/time
https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/_history?_since=2024-07-25T07:00:00Z

I hope these bring you a step closer to a solution?

Your first sample URL has two quote signs (/Patient?_history?_since ...). According to the standard, the first one should be rather a slash, which produces a different result.

You're correct, thanks for picking this up @jaime, i have corrected the example. I believe I was fortunate because "In general, servers SHOULD ignore unknown or unsupported parameters" as per http://hl7.org/fhir/R4/search.html#errors
